# GWT: HighChart error '$wnd.Highcharts' is null or not an object

Tags: gwt, highcharts

I am trying to run a simple High chart in my GWT Application 
but getting this error

```
         '$wnd.Highcharts' is null or not an object
```

my OnModule

```
     public void onModuleLoad() {
      RootPanel.get().add(createChart());  
}  

public Chart createChart() {  

    Chart chart = new Chart()
       .setType(Series.Type.SPLINE)
       .setChartTitleText("Lawn Tunnels")
       .setMarginRight(10);
    Series series = chart.createSeries()
       .setName("Moles per Yard")
       .setPoints(new Number[] { 163, 203, 276, 408, 547, 729, 628 });
    chart.addSeries(series);
    return chart;  
}
```

}

my xml

```
     <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff.                        -->
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
   <inherits name="org.moxieapps.gwt.highcharts.Highcharts"/>
```

my HTML

```
       </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/themes/dark-blue.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modules/exporting.js"></script>

</script>
```

included this jar file in my classpath

```
                 org.moxieapps.gwt.highcharts-1.1.3.jar
```

Any suggestion

Thanks

Comment: Please do not add new questions, update your existing question with new information

Comment: Are you telling the OP: "Please do not add new questions, NOR update your existing question with new information", or are you telling "Please do not add new questions, BUT update your existing question with new information"??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use another javascript library .

"Highcharts needs only two JS files to run: The highcharts.js core and either the jQuery, MooTools or Prototype framework"

Answer (score 1):

I guess you already know the answer for this..
Please include Jquery.js befor highcharts.js